# Как вытащить из тела HTML информацию о медиа объекте?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="//site.ua/uploads/uppod.swf" id="videoplayer15841" style="visibility: visible;" width="688" height="464">

<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
<param name="id" value="videoplayer15841">
<param name="flashvars" value="uid=videoplayer15841&amp;st=//site.ua/img/123123.txt&amp;pl=http://site.ua/speacker.txt">
</object>
```

как вытащить значения содержащиеся в value этотого медийного объекта?

```
value="uid=videoplayer15841&amp;st=//site.ua/img/123123.txt&amp;pl=http://site.ua/speacker.txt">
```

обычно хватал тело с помощью Nokogiri примерно так:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link))
doc.css(".linker")
```

Но не получается таким методом подобраться к объккту

пробовал ещё так:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link))
param = doc.css('param')
param['value']
```

Наверное для медиа объектов нужно что то другое юзать ?

Answer (score 0):

**Просто HTML не предполагает, что в атрибутах может быть что-то умнее строк.** Поэтому ничего кроме строк (и `nil` для атрибутов, которых нет) Nokogiri при получении атрибута и не вернёт. Однако, то, что получает из HTML информацию, может иметь какие-то свои соображения о кодировании информации, т. е. здесь один формат в другом.

Было это:

```
markup = <<HTML
  <param name="flashvars" value="uid=videoplayer15841&amp;st=//site.ua/img/123123.txt&amp;pl=http://site.ua/speacker.txt">
HTML
```

Nokogiri снимает экранирование уровня HTML (аналогично XML, `&amp;` заменились на `&`):

```
require 'nokogiri'
flashvars = Nokogiri::HTML(markup).at_css('param')['value']
# => "uid=videoplayer15841&st=//site.ua/img/123123.txt&pl=http://site.ua/speacker.txt"
```

И остаются данные в [Flash-специфичном формате параметров](https://helpx.adobe.com/ru/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html#main_Use_FlashVars_to_pass_values_to_a_SWF_file), которые, совершенно случайно, очень похожи на [формат кодирования пар ключ-значение в строке запроса](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), которые можно развернуть в хэшмап с помощью `CGI.parse`:

```
require 'cgi'
CGI.parse(flashvars)
# => {"uid"=>["videoplayer15841"],
#     "st"=>["//site.ua/img/123123.txt"],
#     "pl"=>["http://site.ua/speacker.txt"]}
```

Структура результата может показаться странной, но она наиболее правильная, т. к. предполагает, что ключ может встречаться в строке несколько раз.

Comment: И минус без объяснений. Ок :)

Answer (score -1):

```
string_value=doc.xpath("//object@id='videoplayer15841'/param@name='flashvars'").to_s
hash_value=string_value.split(';').map{|i|i.split('=')}.to_h
```

как то так наверное?

Comment: Во-первых, предикат в XPath полагается заключать в квадратные скобки, вроде `param[@name='flashvars']`. Во-вторых, это не работает (даже если поправить XPath; попробуйте сами). В третьих, даже если бы это вообще работало, это давало бы неверный ответ, т. к. внутри HTML значение с XML-экранированием.

Comment: Ну я и написал наверное, не заглядывая в справочник, поясните про xml экранирование плз, что то я впервые слышу такое

Comment: str=doc.xpath("object[@id='videoplayer15841']//param[@name='flashvars']").first['value']
вот так оно работает таки заставили уточнить)) получаем чистый стринг из value

Comment: З.Ы. В нокогири есть великолепный метод parse_html если про экраны и пр, а применять ясен, пень к Nokogiri::HTML этот умница ищет используя xpath в любом даже не очень валидном html после parse_html ессено

Comment: Вот это уже почти дело, внесите в ответ. Правда, это тоже даст неправильный ответ, если в значениях будут URL-небезопасные символы :) Но в вопросе их таки нет.